# Spyder workspace imports cause multiprocessing module to freeze?

Tags: python, import, multiprocessing, spyder

I've recently run into a problem in which I'm trying to use python's multiprocessing module and data imported from a Spyder workspace, but if I reference the imported data a single time in the main module the multiprocessing module just seems to freeze.  I've included example code below in which AvgRT1 is the imported data:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

a=AvgRT1

def runEnvironment():
    return 7

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=1)
    results=pool.apply(runEnvironment)
    pool.close() 
    print results
```

Any idea why this code doesn't terminate?

Comment: Oh, sorry, that is the datum being imported.  In this case, its just a float.

Comment: @Peter I've run into a similar problem, did you figure this out in the end?